# Is reflection necessary if I use "if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11)"

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that targets API 11 (3.0) but minSDKVersion is 7 (2.1).

I generate my PreferenceActivity programmatically instead of with XML.  In Honeycomb, preference layouts have a built-in spot for an icon that can go next to each preference. You can set it with `prefScreen.setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);`

So I don't want to do this on API 7-10. Is this sufficient protection from crashes?

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11)
    prefScreen.setIcon(R.drawable.myIcon);
```

The more elaborate solution that I know is safe is to use reflection to check if that method exists before trying to use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html, it's implied that it's safe to use the SDK_INT constant on Android 2.0 and above to wrap calls to newer APIs, without using reflection.

> Caution: Using the SDK_INT to prevent older system's from executing
>   new APIs works in this way on Android 2.0 (API level 5) and higher
>   only. Older versions will encounter a runtime exception.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            //code 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the method is not available on a lower versions of the platform, it will crash when the file is loaded by the system (it won't even make it to execution of your `if` statement)

You should look at the article on Lazy Loading to do the reflection on the [Android Dev Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html)

Comment: Not true... this is working fine on my phone running 2.2. Just not sure if it's 100% safe. I'll look into the lazy loading, thanks.

Comment: Interesting, I was under the impression that all methods were validated when the class was loaded for the first time and would prevent those type of `if` statements from working. Either way, Lazy Loading is the better way to handle these types of ambiguities when dealing with older platform versions.

Comment: Yes, after reading up some more on it, it looks like it should have crashed when loading the class. Not sure why it didn't.

Comment: @TenFour04 It looks like some of the older versions of android have a more aggressive classloader (specifically < 1.6) that checks *everything* when it loads your files, but newer versions (2.1+) don't bother until you actually try calling them which allows the `if` statements to work. I'm not sure how stable these `if`s are but they seem to do the job on the newer versions of android. That said, sometimes lazy loading is just cleaner code :)

Comment: I'm not sure even older ones were more aggressive. From the above article: "The ClassLoader loads classes lazily and will only load and verify classes on first access." That means it will load only when you try to access it. If you never run the code inside the if, you won't access it, so it won't be loaded.