# Android View animation - poor performance on big screens

Tags: android, performance, animation

I developed a puzzle game. In my game I have several custom views, which are nested inside FrameLayout, like layers. Each view displays a bitmap. The largest bitmap is the game board and it takes about 2/3 of screen size. There is also background image under the FrameLayout.

When user touches the screen, simple view animations are performed with this game board view - it can be rotated or flipped.

It all works fine on small screens, but users reported performance issues on Galaxy Tab - there's a noticeable lag just before animation starts and animation itself is not smooth. (Game board bitmap size on these screens is about 600*600px)

Here's my layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootFrame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImageLayer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/gameFrame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.mygame.BoardView
            android:id="@+id/boardLayer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

            <com.mygame.SomeObjectView
            android:id="@+id/someObjectLayer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

            <com.mygame.SomeOtherObjectView
            android:id="@+id/someOtherObjectLayer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        </FrameLayout>    

</FrameLayout>
```

And here is my BoardView class.

```
public class BoardView extends View {

Bitmap b;
int x;
int y;

public BoardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // calculate size of the bitmap
    b = Bitmap.createBitmap(sizeX, sizeY, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    createMyBitmap();
}

private void createMyBitmap() {
    Canvas c;
    c = new Canvas(b);
    // lots of c.drawRect() and c.drawLine() , using opaque and semi-transparent colors
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(b, x, y, null);
}
}
```

And a snippet where I do the animation, it's pretty simple:

```
AnimationRotate anim1=new AnimationRotate(startAngle,endAngle,centerX,centerY);
anim1.setDuration(500);
anim1.setInterpolator(newDecelerateInterpolator());
startAnimation(anim1);
```

So what causes lags with view animation and how can I fix it? 
Is my approach correct or maybe I should use SurfaceView or frame animation or something else?

Comment: Your root frame layout, does this need to be a frame or could you use a relative? I am mobile atm so I can't access the post but there was one on the use of layouts which summed up to using relative layouts or linear for better performance. I have taken to this approach and it seems to work quite well.

Comment: I will try to use relative layout instead of frame and see if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, all 2D-Graphic commands are very slow, and keep on slow down, when the screen is going bigger. I would advise to set up a 3D-Surfaceview to put your images as textures on quads, and render it. This will be much faster than with 2D-Gfx.

Answer (score 11):

Enable Hardware Acceleration if you haven't already. The layout rendering system was modified in 3.0+ to improve performance on these large screens by moving *most* of the software rendering into hardware.  You care read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

There are certain things that will not work work with the hardware acceleration but from what you have shown you are fine.  The simplest way to enable it is to add this to your application's manifest and target 3.0 or higher (as in to build against, you can still support lower api levels)

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
...
>
```

Comment: So I made the following modifications to the manifest:
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ....

But it shows an error "No resource identifier found for attribute hardwareAccelerated". Does it mean that I have to change API level to 11 for my project? Will the app run on v 2.1 after that?

Comment: Yes you have to change it to api 11. So long as you don't call any classes/methods that don't exist in 2.1 it will still run. XML attributes are different, if a lower api level finds unknown attributes, it just ignores them (doesn't crash)  There is a whole bunch of stuff related to backwards compatibility on the android dev blog, heres another answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891176/is-reflection-necessary-if-i-use-if-android-os-build-version-sdk-int-11/6891250#6891250

Comment: Well, I tried to add hardwareAccelerated="true", but it causes crashes on devices with android 3.0 and higher. It throws NullPointerException on line: canvas.setMatrix(null);
So I had to revert to my old manifest file..

Comment: Well either you canvas is null or it doesn't want a null matrix. I would pursue this further. You can open another question if you need to debug it more, but try checking for null and use an identity matrix (aka new Matrix())

Comment: Description of "setMatrix" says that if matrix is null, it is set to identity.. The code works on 3.0 emulator, but crashes on real 3.0 devices. Unfortunately, I only have 2.2 phone and I can't experiment on real users, so the only option for me is to remove this parameter..

Comment: This was absolutely the correct answer for me with a very similar problem. Yes, you can completely re-write things as the accepted answer suggests, but often that is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

I've read that setting the following properties can help improve performance:

```
this.setAnimationCacheEnabled(true);
this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you read from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

```
View.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotationY", 180);
animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
    }
});
animator.start();
```

Comment: I think this is untrue.  Look at the note on the documentation..

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Note: You currently cannot enable hardware acceleration at the view level. View layers have other functions besides disabling hardware acceleration. See View layers for more information about their uses.

Comment: That part of the doc might be out of date or just not written very clearly. I've toggled hardware layers on views and can definitely see a difference in both behavior and rendering.